# wxOSX/Carbon: wxGLCanvas mouse offset in non-floating window classes

Tags: opengl, mouse, wxwidgets, macos-carbon, wxglcanvas

I mainly program plugins using wxWidgets within a Carbon bundle which is
loaded at runtime. The host-applications where my plugins are running in
provide a native window handle (`WindowRef`), which I can use to add my custom,
wxWidgets-based GUI-classes.

To use the native window handle with wxWidgets
classes I had to write a `wxTopLevelWindow` wrapper class, which does all the
`WindowRef` encapsulation. So far, this works pretty well, but under some
circumstances I got vertical mouse offsets within a `wxGLCanvas` if the window
class of the native window handle is not of the type "`kFloatingWindowClass`".
I am able to bypass the problem if I display an info panel (`wxPanel`) over the
whole `wxGlCanvas` and if the user hides the info panel then the mouse offset
is gone.

Now my questions:

1. Is there a "simple" explanation for this behaviour?
2. Is it possible to use certain method calls to imitate info panel effect
   without using the panel itself? I tried several combinations of `Update()` and
   `Refresh()` calls of all involved components, but none of them worked so far.
   Even the use of `wxSizer` couldn't help here.

#### Window hierarchy used by plugin-applications:

```
wxCustomTopLevelWindow (WindowRef provided by host-application)
 wxPanel (parent window for all application panel)
  wxPanel (application info panel)
  wxPanel (application main panel)
   wxPanel (opengl main panel)
    wxGlCanvas (main opengl canvas)
```

Any ideas? Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a co-ordinate system mismatch? Some Mac OS X APIs use the top-left as the origin (positive y goes down), whereas others use the lower-left (positive y goes up).

This can seem intermittent, as the error will be small near the vertical center of the screen; farther from the center, the co-ordinate will appear to be wildly inaccurate (indeed, it's on the opposite side of the screen).

> I am able to bypass the problem if I display an info panel (`wxPanel`) over the whole `wxGlCanvas` and if the user hides the info panel then the mouse offset is gone.

This could be a red herring, if you were popping up this panel in the middle of the screen and closing it with the mouse.

Comment: Hey Peter,
thanks for your answer. The wxGlCanvas itself is drawn on the correct position, but the mouse has always a constant offset whether I'm in the center or far from the center. The coordinate system mismatch migth be a problem, but to verify this I have debug this in depth. Are you familiar with the wxWidgets API?

Comment: It's actually a bit more (26-28 pixels) as of the title bar (22 pixels). But I will measure the exact offset.

Comment: The menu bar is also 22 pixels; that's what I was thinking.